# How to collect a list of int to a list of entry in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I have an integer array `int[]` and would like to create an `List` of entries that contains:

```
class Entry {
   int theIndexOfNumber;
   int numberInTheArray;
}
```

For example, for `{3,5,7},` I would like to have a list of

```
{1, 3}, {2, 5},(3, 7}
```

This is easy using some Java code but I want to do it in a Java 8 way using stream.

I think I should use some sort of collector but don't know how to write this. Can someone please help?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Entry(i + 1, array[i]))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the indices of the array using an `IntStream` and map each index to the corresponding `Entry` instance:

```
int[] arr = ...
List<Entry> entries =
    IntStream.range(0,arr.length)
             .mapToObj(i -> new Entry(i+1,arr[i]))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is assuming `Entry` has the required constructor.